# How to prove this simple fact from probability: $P(A)+P(B) = P(A\cup B)+P(A\cap B)$

Tags: probability

I want to show that for events $A,B \subseteq \Omega$, $P(A)+P(B) = P(A\cup B)+P(A\cap B)$. This is obviously true, but I'm having trouble thinking of the way to prove it. Does anyone have a neat, short proof? How should I best show this?

Comment: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Inclusion-Exclusion_Principle

Answer (score 3):

$$A = (A\cap B) \cup (A\setminus B)$$ with disjoint union, hence
$$P(A) = P(A\cap B) + P(A\setminus B)$$
$$P(A) + P(B)= P(A\cap B) + P(A\setminus B) + P(B)$$
and 
$$A\cup B = B \cup (A\setminus B)$$ with disjoint union again, so
$$P(A) + P(B)= P(A\cap B) + \underbrace{P(A\setminus B) + P(B)}_{P(B \cup (A\setminus B))} = P(A\cap B) + P(A\cup B)$$